# Python return error while writing data into file(Python 2.7)

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am parsing XML file with python mini-Dom module.while writing data into file its giving error like **`Unicode Encode Error: 'ASCII' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)`**. But Out put prints perfectly on command line  Please tell me the solution.

my XML file is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Feature>
        <Word Root  ="ਨੌਕਰ-ਚਾਕਰ">
            <info Inflection  ="ਨੌਕਰਾਂ-ਚਾਕਰਾਂ">
        <posinfo gender  ="Masculine" number  ="Plural" case  ="Oblique" />

                </info>
        </Word>
                </Feature>
```

My python code is:

```
import sys

from xml.dom import minidom

file=open("npu.txt","w+")
doc = minidom.parse("NPU.xml")
word = doc.getElementsByTagName("Word")
for each in word:
    # print "root"+each.getAttribute("Root")
    file.write(each.getAttribute("Root")+"\n")
    hh=each.getElementsByTagName("info")

    for each1 in hh:
        # print "inflection"+each1.getAttribute("Inflection")
        file.write(each1.getAttribute("Inflection")+"\t")

        vv=each1.getElementsByTagName("posinfo")
        for each2 in vv:
            # print each2.getAttribute("gender")
            # print each2.getAttribute("number")
            # print each2.getAttribute("case")
            file.write( each2.getAttribute("gender")+",")
            file.write( each2.getAttribute("number")+",")
            file.write(each2.getAttribute("case"))
        file.write("\n")
    file.write("--------\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
encode data while writing-
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
file=open("npu.txt","w+") 
file.write("ਨੌਕਰ-ਚਾਕਰ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the way you parse the XML, this is an encoding problem.

The error is caused by the encoding of your text (UTF-8).
You are trying to write your text as ASCII that doesn't include the characters that you are using.

try with codecs as follow:

```
import codecs

file = codecs.open("npu.txt", "w+", "utf-8")
file.write("ਨੌਕਰ-ਚਾਕਰ".decode('utf-8'))
file.close()
```

EDIT :

You can also set the default encoding to UTF-8 adding the special comment 
`# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` 
at the beginning of the python source. The default encoding is ASCII (7-bit).
Note that Python identifiers are still restricted to ASCII characters.